# Define Collection's Model from model method

Tags: typescript, collections, model

I'm trying to get the current Collection Model in typescript, but only can get the main Model class, and not the extended one.

I have this `.d.ts`:

```
declare class Collection extends Base {
  models: Model[];

  constructor(
    models?: Model[],
    options?: Options,
    attributes?: Record<string, any>
  );

  model(): typeof Model;

  find(where: Predicate): Model | undefined;
}

declare class Model extends Base {
}
```

So I have `Categories` collection and `Category` model.

```
export default class Categories extends Collection {
  model() {
    return Category;
  }
}

export default class Category extends Model {
}
```

But when I do :

```
const obCategories = new Categories();
await obCategories.fetch();
const obCategory = obCategories.find({ is_default: true });
```

`find()` returns `Model` instead of `Category`.
How can I define, in .d.ts, a type Model that reads `model` returns method in `Collection`.?

I hope was cleared.
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your `find` method returns a `Model | undefined` type. What you want is to return a `Category | undefined` if I understood it correctly.

In order to achieve this, you'll need to use parametric polymorphism. More specifically, your `Collection` data type must take a type parameter to tell the compiler what kind of model it holds. In your case, `Categories` is a `Collection` of `Category` models.

To do that, you can use the following syntax:

```js
// we need this utility type for the return type of the model() method
type ConstructorOf<A> = new (...args: any[]) => A;

declare class Collection<A extends Model> extends Base {
  models: A[];

  constructor(
    models?: A[],
    options?: Options,
    attributes?: Record<string, any>
  );

  model(): ConstructorOf<A>;

  find(where: Predicate): A | undefined;
}

class Categories extends Collection<Category> {
  ...
}

const obCategory = obCategories.find({ is_default: true }); // Category | undefined
```

Here's the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).